# Is Cauchy's formula apt for evaluating this integral

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate the following.
$$\frac{1}{2i}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{s \sin{(sr)}}{(s-k)(s+k)}\mathrm{d}s,$$
with $k$ and $r$ being real constants.

The integral could be written as
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{s e^{isr}}{(s-k)(s+k)}\mathrm{d}s-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{s e^{-isr}}{(s-k)(s+k)}\mathrm{d}s,$$
which makes it nicer, as it looks appropriate to use Cauchy's integral formula.
But the problem I have is that the poles lie right on the real interval, so is it possible to exploit Cauchy's formula in such a case?

Comment: Not the integral formula, but the residue theorem, provided you interpret the integral as a principal value integral (the singularities at $\pm k$ aren't integrable, so it doesn't exist as a proper Riemann or Lebesgue integral [except for some special values of $r$]).

Comment: [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804655/integral-ia-b-p-int-0-pi-fracd-thetaa-b-cos-theta) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644002/what-happens-when-lvert-omega-rvert-1) for a short explanation of how to treat simple poles on the contour of integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{{1 \over 2\ic}\,\pp\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
     {s\sin\pars{sr} \over \pars{s - k}\pars{s + k}}\,\dd s:\ {\large ?}}$.

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{{1 \over 2\ic}\,\pp\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> {s\sin\pars{sr} \over \pars{s - k}\pars{s + k}}\,\dd s}
> ={\sgn\pars{r} \over 2\ic}\,\pp\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> {s\sin\pars{\verts{r}s} \over \pars{s - k}\pars{s + k}}\,\dd s
> \\[3mm]&={\sgn\pars{r} \over 4\ic}\,\pp\bracks{%
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{\verts{r}s} \over s + k}\,\dd s
> +\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{\verts{r}s} \over s - k}\,\dd s}
> \\[3mm]&={\sgn\pars{r} \over 4\ic}\,\pp\bracks{%
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{\verts{r}s}\cos\pars{\verts{r}k} \over s}\,\dd s
> +\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{\verts{r}s}\cos\pars{\verts{r}k} \over s}
> \,\dd s}
> \\[3mm]&={\sgn\pars{r} \over 2\ic}\,\cos\pars{\verts{r}k}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{s} \over s}\,\dd s
> ={\sgn\pars{r} \over 2\ic}\,\cos\pars{\verts{r}k}\,\pi
> \end{align}

$$
\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over 2\ic}\,\pp\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{s\sin\pars{sr} \over \pars{s - k}\pars{s + k}}\,\dd s
={\pi \over 2\ic}\,\sgn\pars{r}\cos\pars{r\,k}}
$$

Comment: Though not exactly what I asked for, but this helped a lot